# Elastic Beanstalk: Deploy branch to env

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm considering migration for custom hosted Rails app to Elastic Beanstalk.

I've create a simple Rails app and manage to deploy it to on Elastic beanstalk. There are still a few thing I still didn't manage to get:

1. How can I deploy a branch or a specific code to my app?
2. Is the deployed version is from last commit or my current workspace?
3. What are the best practices when handling deployment on Beanstalk?

Amazon have this document ([link](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/command-reference-branch-environment.html)) but it seems to be deprecated and I can't figure how to do it on current version

`elad:...$ eb --version
EB CLI 3.7 (Python 2.7.1)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure my solution is the best practices or not, I just show here, welcome all comments on this.

> 1. How can I deploy a branch or a specific code to my app?

- Beanstalk support deploy the last commit in current branch (which was actually uploaded to S3 firstly) by using [EB command line](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/eb3-deploy.html)
- Deploy from a zipped file which was also actually updated to S3 after that
  Here is what in in your environment settings in Beanstalk console

[image]

[image]

> 2. Is the deployed version is from last commit or my current workspace?

- From last commit

> 3.What are the best practices when handling deployment on Beanstalk?

**My solution #1:** Define which branch will be deployed to a specific environment

In `.elasticbeanstalk/config.yml`

```
# .....
branch-defaults:
  develop:
    environment: mercury-dev-staging
  master:
    environment: mercury-dev
# .....
```

Relying on this config, I always switch to `develop` branch to deploy to `mercury-dev-staging` env, and `master` one for `mercury-dev`. This will avoid some mistakes like deploying `develop` branch to production env

**My solution #2:** Define some alias commands for quick deployment:

In `~/.bash_profile` (I'm using MacOS)

```
alias deploy_production="eb deploy mercury-dev;"
alias deploy_staging="eb deploy mercury-dev-staging;"
```

Now I just type `deploy_staging` for staging deployment, this is convenient but risky, because you may deploy your developing feature to production.

Comment: I use option 1. I like the simplicity of it.

Comment: @Clarkie: any idea for other solutions?

Comment: @hieuPham thanks. I was fighting BeanStalk for couple of days now and decided it just not good enough - at least for hosting Rails apps. The lack of RVM / RBenv or gem management generates LOTS of issues for even a small Rails app... too bad for AWS, I'm very disappointed.

Answer (score 0):

Someone considering their options could take a look at [AWS Code Pipeline](https://aws.amazon.com/codepipeline/). You define the specific GitHub repo branch. If you push a change to that branch, Code Pipeline detects it and starts a pipeline process.

This is relevant to Elastic Beanstalk because on Step 4 of Code Pipeline, you can deploy to AWS Elastic Beanstalk (among others).

[image: AWS CodePipeline]